# Unknown column in where clause, but columns is specified in select

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the following query

```
SELECT COALESCE(curr_bid, start_bid) AS `bid`, `lot`.*, (SELECT COUNT(id) from bid where lot_id=lot.id) as bids_count FROM `lot` LEFT JOIN (SELECT `lot_step`.`id`, `lot_step`.`lot_id`, max(amount) as curr_bid FROM `lot_step` GROUP BY `lot_step`.`lot_id`) `ls` ON lot.id = ls.lot_id  WHERE ((`bid` >= '100') AND (`bid` <= '100000000'))
```

But I always get `Unknown column 'bid' in 'where clause'`. Not sure how can this happen, because I specified the column after SELECT

Comment: You can't use an alias in a  `where` clause

Comment: @juergen d So how should i refer to the custom column?

Comment: Just retype it: `COALESCE(curr_bid, start_bid)`

Comment: @juergend Your are right, now it works as it supposed to. Thanks for the help!